# What does the score mean in campaign missions?

Tags: frozen-synapse

After completing a campaign mission in Frozen Synapse, I am presented with a "score".  This seems to consist of a number and a symbol.  But so far I haven't really seen a correlation between how I thought I performed in the mission and either the number or the symbol.  So what are they supposed to represent?

Comment: My guess is they take the ideal option and check how you do. I'm thinking the less units are killed the higher the score, and the less turns it takes the higher the score.

Comment: @Rafael That's what I would guess too, but what I've seen so far doesn't seem to coincide with that.

Comment: Well for example in the second mission where you have to kill all the scientists it took me 2 turns to kill them all and it gave me a 100 score wich is max i think. You could try and kill them all in 5 turns and see what the score is. And then you could try and kill the bare minimum in 5 turns and see what the score is then.

Comment: I agree that the scoring is vague and confusing. I recently played a mission where the goal was to collect 3 of the 5 data disks within 15 turns. I collected all 5 disks and killed all the enemies while losing no units myself, in 10 turns, and only got bronze. I guess that mission judged score primarily by number of turns, but there was no way to know that going in.

Answer (score 9):

The symbol is a medal (3 yellow cubes for gold, 2 grey for silver and 1 reddish for bronze).
The number is also how well you've been doing but Mode 7 had no time to tell me what determined it nor the medal. It seems to be different for each mission type and is not always consistent.
Also the high score shown in the main window with the seed etc is supposed to be your best score but it's not at all cause it's bugged.
In relation to this you might want to have a look at the [Frozen Synapse Campaign Missions Records](http://icebrain.net/tournaments/campaign-missions-records/) to compare scores and try to find the formula (why not).